# The method checkCollision(BoundingShape) is undefined for the type Object

Tags: java, object, undefined

Im getting the error in the title in this code:

```
private boolean isOnGroud(LevelObject obj, Tile[][] mapTiles) {

    ArrayList<Tile> tiles = obj.getBoundingShape().getGroundTiles(mapTiles);

    obj.getBoundingShape().movePosition(0, 1);

    for (Tile t : tiles) {
        if (t.getBoundingShape() != null) {
            if ((t.getBoundingShape()).checkCollision(obj.getBoundingShape())) {
                obj.getBoundingShape().movePosition(0, -1);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Specifically on: "if ((t.getBoundingShape()).checkCollision(obj.getBoundingShape()))"

Any ideas why? The redline for this error is under .checkCollision, heres a link to the full Class files code: http://pastebin.com/P6Q8v40m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the reason is simple, the method returns an `Object`, which simply has no method `checkCollision()`. You need to cast it to a type which has this method.

Comment: Thanks that soled it, I feel dumb!

Comment: Good, glad to help, consider accepting the answer then ;)

Comment: Won't let me for another 8 minutes:( Do you think you could help me solve another issue I'm having with an Arraylist? I posted it as a question on here too.